# ReferenceError: require is not defined @react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I made my own `react` component `npm package` and published in npm, now when import and use it in other CRA apps, i get this error when `npm start` in run in command line .[image: Browser Error]

and in console:

[image: Console Error]

My webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
                use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=512&&name=[path][name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development',
    externals: {
        'react': 'commonjs react'
    }
};
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "primetable1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Datatable for react apps based on Primereact",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "primereact",
    "primeicons"
  ],
  "author": "Anish Arya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.19",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primereact": "^3.4.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

My .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": ["env"],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread",
      "transform-react-jsx",
      "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ]
  }
```

I followed this article to create and publish npm package: 
https://codeburst.io/extracting-a-react-js-component-and-publishing-it-on-npm-2a49096757f5

How to solve this error?

Comment: I think the `externals` configuration is bogus here. Try removing it.

Comment: `require('webpack')`, where is `webpack` in your `package.json`? It's not there.

Comment: @JMadelaine That's a concern, but it doesn't really matter since `webpack-cli` etc. pull them in anyway.

Comment: FWIW, here's a webpack.config.js for a React component that Works For Me (tm): https://github.com/akx/react-wheely/blob/6dc8d5408efde6d3d29fda09c499c1b19e1de06a/webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `externals` configuration seems wrong – you probably only need `externals: [nodeExternals()]` (from `const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");`).